# Replacing chars in returned output bash

Tags: linux, bash, replace

im tryng to run this command to grep the exploit MS-* from metasploit exploit's dir

```
locate -r "\.rb$" | xargs grep "MSB" | grep metasploit | grep exploit | grep smb | awk '{print $3,$4}'
```

i got this result :

> grep: /usr/share/doc/ruby-http-parser.rb: Is a directory
>
> 'MS17-010'],
>
> 'MSB', 'MS03-049'
>
> 'MSB', 'MS04-007'],
>
> 'MSB', 'MS04-011'
>
> 'MSB', 'MS04-031'],
>
> 'MSB', 'MS05-039'
>
> 'MSB', 'MS06-025'
>
> 'MSB', 'MS06-025'
>
> 'MSB', 'MS06-040'
>
> 'MSB', 'MS06-066'],
>
> 'MSB', 'MS06-066'],
>
> 'MSB', 'MS06-070'
>
> 'MS07-029']
>
> MS08-067),
>
> 'MSB', 'MS09-050'

how i can remove this ('MSB', ' ) and ('])from each line

i need output like this :

> MS09-050
>
> MS08-067
>
> MS06-070
>
> ..
>
> ..
>
> ..

and also i need to remove the first line ( grep: /usr/share/doc/ruby-http-parser.rb: Is a directory )

Comment: If the pattern is always _MS two digits dash three digits_, you could just use e.g.: `egrep -o 'MS[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{3}'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
locate -r "\.rb$" | xargs grep -s "MSB" | grep metasploit | grep exploit | grep smb | awk '{print $3,$4}'|sed "s/[,')]//g" |sed "s/MSB //g"|sed "s/]//g"
```

**Explanation:**

- `sed "s/[,')]//g"` - removes `,` `'` and `)` from each line.
- `sed "s/MSB //g"|sed "s/]//g"` - removes `MSB` from each line.
- `sed "s/]//g"` - removes `]`
- `xargs grep -s "MSB"` - the `-s` option in grep will suppress error messages for that output.

Comment: The message `is a directory` is printed on STDERR (@Anonymous: And it is **not** the first line of the output. It just happens to be printed before the rest, because STDERR is usually unbuffered), so you have to use `2>&1` before applying `grep -v`.

Comment: Good catch, advising to add the `-s` option to remove the error message in the first place